# How to imitate string.Format() in my own method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, methods

I have an object with a custom `WriteLine(string)` method. Something like this:

```
public void WriteLine(string text)
{
    this.StringList.Add(text);
}
```

What is the easiest way to duplicate the functionality of `string.Format()` with this method? For example: What I currently often find myself doing is this:

```
myObj.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello, {0}", name));
```

If you create a new Console application their version of a `WriteLine()` method does exactly what I would prefer to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name);
```

They eliminate the need to call `string.Format()`. Is it easy to make your method accept this somehow? Or am I going to have to create a thousand method overloads? Something like this:

```
public void WriteLine() { ... }

public void WriteLine(string text) { ... }

public void WriteLine(string text, object arg0) { ... }

public void WriteLine(string text, object arg0, object arg1) { ... }

public void WriteLine(string text, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
{
    this.StringList.Add(string.Format(text, arg0, arg1, arg2));
}

// etc etc etc
```

Is that the only logical way to do this? Any suggestions are welcomed :)

Comment: Why not just delegate to `string.Format`? Do you really want to write a tokenizer?

Comment: There's a feature of C# that you don't know about that you need to know about. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Oded that's my question... I was unaware of the `params` keyword and did not know that I even ***could*** delegate to `string.Format`.

Comment: Fair enough Alex - I didn't realize that was the issue :)

Comment: Just be careful with params; if a "params" method is applicable in its *normal* form then it is not called in its *expanded* form. For example, "WriteLine("", null)" calls WriteLine *with a null array*. "WriteLine("", (object)null)" calls WriteLine with an array containing a single null.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to copy the method signature from string.format.

```
public void WriteLine(string text,params object[] args) {
  this.StringList.Add(string.Format(text,args));
}
```

As suggested by ChaosPandion you can also include overloads to prevent array creation

```
public void WriteLine(string text) {
  this.StringList.Add(text);
}

public void WriteLine(string text,object arg0) {
  this.StringList.Add(string.Format(text, arg0));
}

public void WriteLine(string text,object arg0, object arg1) {
  this.StringList.Add(string.Format(text, arg0, arg1));
}

public void WriteLine(string text,object arg0, object arg1, object arg2) {
  this.StringList.Add(string.Format(text, arg0, arg1, arg2));
}
```

I wouldn't go past arg2 as string.format doesn't so the benefit disappears.

Comment: Perfect! I'm always glad when I take the time to post a proper question before wasting time doing something tedious. There's almost always a better way. Thanks!

Comment: I would add overloads to avoid Array creation for simple cases. Maybe up to 4 args.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Good suggestion. I took your advice.

Comment: Why use the StringList? why not directly write to the string?

Answer (score 8):

There is one edge case you might want to take pains to avoid. The following code will write the string **{0}** to the console

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}");
```

However, you use one of the implementations of WriteLine suggested by others in this answer, those implementations will throw an exception:

```
WriteLine("{0}"); //throws exception
```

The easiest fix is either to have two overloads of WriteLine or to modify the suggested code slightly to handle the edge case:

```
public void WriteLine(string text,params object[] args) {
  var message=args.Length==0 ? text : string.Format(text, args);
  this.StringList.Add(message);
}
```

Comment: I already had an overload for just string so that is not a problem for me. Thanks for calling attention to that :)

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
 public void WriteLine(string text, params object[] parameters)
 {
     //..
 }
```